# Jmeter summary report data communication in master-slave mode

Tags: jmeter, rmi, jmeter-plugins, master-slave

AS we know Jmeter have 2 mode to run test plans: single and master-slave mode

in single mode Jmeter summary report listener will collect min, max, stddev, error%,etc data and write in a file..

but in master-slave mode, these information are record by master server, and I have checked the Jmeter summary report codes, I can't understand which extends, methods or which codes make Jmeter slave servers can communicate with master server to let master server record these data, same question in Simple Data Writer listener.

So, can anyone help on this question, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter's slave communicate with master thanks to [Java RMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation). For this reason you need to [start RMI registry](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#detail_instructions) before test. Since version 2.3.1 you don't need to do it manually, Jmeter server wil, take care of this.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, actually I have a jar that create by our self and used it to create some report file in Jmeter, but in master-slave mode, each slave create one report, it means that will have many file in slave after test and we only need a summary create in master, Summary report listener, Data writer etc Jmeter plug-in are collect data in master, I think is that I miss some import or some methods in my code?

Comment: To merge result *.jtl files you can use [Merge results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) plugin.
Or you can try commercial Jmeter's fork [SmartMeter](https://www.smartmeter.io/). One of its features is distributed load testing, where SmartMeter will merge results after test and generate report. More [info](https://www.smartmeter.io/blog/jmeter-distributed-load-testing-made-simple).
Other options to merge results could be Redline13's [Merged result files](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/04/pricing-and-features/) or  [Blazemeter's sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/)